# WPF InitializeComponent is not recognized

Tags: c#, wpf

Completely new to WPF and following a Microsoft walkthrough which asked to replace the XML with the following:

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Northwind Orders" Height="335" Width="425" 
        Name="OrdersWindow" Loaded="Window1_Loaded">
    <Grid Name="orderItemsGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="258*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="161*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="OrderID" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" 
                  Height="23" Margin="92,12,37.703,0" Name="comboBoxOrder" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Order_Details}"  
                  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"  
                  Name="orderItemsDataGrid" Margin="34,46,34.4,49.6"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Product" Binding="{Binding ProductID, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Price" Binding="{Binding UnitPrice, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Discount" Binding="{Binding Discount, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Label Height="28" Margin="34,12,0,0" Name="orderLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="65">Order:</Label>
        <StackPanel Name="Buttons" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                    Height="40" Margin="0,261,22.4,4.6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,12" 
                Name="buttonSave" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" 
                    Click="buttonSaveChanges_Click">Save Changes
            </Button>
            <Button Height="23" Margin="0,0,12,12" 
                Name="buttonClose" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" 
                    Click="buttonClose_Click">Close</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So I replaced it but now if I go to the file `MainWindow.xmal.cs` the code for `InitializeComponent();` is being highlighted as not existing.

[image]

Why is this and how do I correct it?

Comment: There are a couple of event handlers used in that XAML that should be declared in code behind (in MainWindow.xaml.cs), like Window1_Loaded, buttonSaveChanges_Click, and buttonClose_Click. You are not supposed to simply copy a bunch of XAML without the code behind parts.

Comment: @Clemens - I was just following this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/wcf/creating-the-dotnet-client-application-wcf-data-services-quickstart#to-create-the-client-application-by-using-visual-studio

Comment: You also have `x:Class="Window1"` in the XAML, which should actually be `x:Class="NorthwindClient.MainWindow"`. I'd suggest you just start over with a new WPF application project in Visual Studio. And an introductory WPF book. My favorite is "WPF Unleashed" by Adam Nathan.

Comment: @clemens thanks for the reference, I just bought that book as WPF looks like cool technology that is worth my time to study.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must match the `x:Class="Window1"` in XAML with code behind class `class MainWindow`.

Change the XAML from `x:Class="Window1"` to `x:Class="NorthwindClient.MainWindow"`